# AppendAllLines alternative solution

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a txt file from C# as follows:

```
 File.WriteAllText("important.txt", Convert.ToString(c));
 File.AppendAllLines("important.txt", (from r in rec
                     select r.name + "   " + r.num1 + "   " + r.num2 + "   " + r.mult + "   " + r.rel).ToArray());
```

I am getting error `AppendAllLInes` not found for system.IO.File any alternative approach or how can I include `AppendAllLInes`

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? AppendAllLines was added in 4.0, or Visual Studio 2010. If you are using a prior version, you will need a different solution.

Comment: i am using visual studio 2008... Can you please suggest me any alternative solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write all at once.

```
var part1 = Convert.ToString(c);
var part2 = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                rec.Select(r => r.name + "   " + r.num1 + "   " + r.num2 + "   " + r.mult + "   " + r.rel)
               .ToArray());
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("important.txt", part1 + part2);
```

You could also use [`WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in 3.5:

```
var allLines = new []{Convert.ToString(c)}
              .Concat(rec.Select(r => r.name + "   " + r.num1 + "   " + r.num2 + "   " + r.mult + "   " + r.rel))
              .ToArray();
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("important.txt", allLines);
```

Comment: I am getting an error in var text = part1 + String.Join(Environment.NewLine, r); it says cannot convert Ilist to string.

Comment: @Csharp_learner: Edited my answer to add `ToArray`. This should work also [in 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).